# Cache Objects - .NET Core

Tags: caching, asp.net-core

Using VS 2017, .NET Core 1.1. JSON calls.

Seems there are lots of libraries around Cache; for example, [CacheManager](https://github.com/MichaCo/CacheManager), [Stack Exchange Redis](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis), [Foundatio](https://github.com/FoundatioFx/Foundatio), etc.

For my project, I objects that do not change often; for example, *countries*, *states*, etc.  Is it so wrong to make a static IEnumerable of say ... *countries*?  Yes, refreshing the static objects becomes a little more cumbersome, one would have to have a controller that could make the object *null* and on the next request repopulate it (Lazy init).  Suppose the Cache class could make all static variables *null* at 6:00 pm, for example.  This is an older approach but still seems to be a good one.  Any real downsides?

Comment: Yes, `static` caches are **wrong/bad** in 99.99% of all cases

Comment: Thanks for the comment, can you lightly explain why?  Is it a memory thing? Data Corruption?  More maintenance if the list changes?  Threading concerns?

Comment: Many things. Code smell, bad practice, threading issues (i.e. when multiple requests access it in between its values being changed), can leak memory (forever holding an reference to an object), hard to unit test, hidden dependencies. Why not just inject `IMemoryCache`, its registered by default in ASP.NET Core iirc and when using `IDistributedCache` which can be in memory for development and Redis for production